# How to write a regex for this expression

Tags: java, regex

i need to write a regex which only lets the (ä,ö,ü,..) int the array..the code bellow also lets white spaces in the array..example `parts2[0]` and `parts2[1]` has white spaces but supposed to be ö

```
String str="geliyoru mamaadsödsödösdä dädsdäsfäfsä  yüwüsüdsüfsäfsfä"
    String[] parts2 = str.split("[A-Za-z]+|[0-9]+|x[A-Fa-f0-9]");
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(str.length());

    for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {

        System.out.println(parts2[i]);
        result.append(parts[i]);


    }
```

Comment: A regex? What do you want to split, what are the expected parts. You need to be more specific.

Comment: sorry, now its better

Comment: But I don't see any strings with `ä`,`ö`, etc. Furthermore there are definitely other ways to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `Pattern.replaceAll` feature of Java.

```
String str= "geliyoru mamaadsödsödösdä dädsdäsfäfsä  yüwüsüdsüfsäfsfä";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^\u00E4\u00F6\u00FC]*");
String result = p.matcher(str).replaceAll("");
```

In the pattern between `[^` and `]` you should enumerate all the characters you wish to preserve using the unicode definition. You can look them op for instance using Google/DuckDuckGo. The `^` part between the square brackets meens that you invert the matching. Thus all character not present in the group are matched. And in the last line all these characters are replaced by empty strings.

For performance, I've added `*` at the end of the regex, such that groups of characters are matched as one and thus replacement is done only once.

You can see a jdoodle [here](http://jdoodle.com/a/66)

Comment: Why not just use String.replaceAll?

Comment: @donfuxx: Internally, `String.replaceAll` will generate a regex. If you however plan to perform this task multiple times, you don't need to recompile the regex each time as it is static.

Comment: String result = p.replaceAll(str,""); gives error somehow...why it can be ? any ideas ?(The method replaceAll(String, String) is undefined for the type Pattern)

Comment: I've added a JDoodle so you can interactively modify your regex.